# Invalid Request for Boto3 Call to Textract

Tags: boto3

I am trying to make a boto3 call to Textract, but am unable to see what's wrong with my code. This is the error message I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 20, in <module>
    'RoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/xxxRole'
  File "/Users/xxx/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxx/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the StartDocumentAnalysis operation: Request has invalid parameters
```

This is my code

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('textract')

response = client.start_document_analysis(
  DocumentLocation={
    'S3Object': {
      'Bucket': 'xxx',
      'Name': 'xxx.pdf'
    }
  },
  FeatureTypes=[
    'TABLES',
    'FORMS'
  ],
  ClientRequestToken='xxx',
  JobTag='xxx',
  NotificationChannel={
    'SNSTopicArn': 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:xxx:xxx',
    'RoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xxxRole'
  }
)
```

I have tried recreating my SNS topic and service roles several times, as well as making sure that my tabs/spaces are correct (for Python's sake). I've also switched the positions of SNSTopicArn and RoleArn, and the error message shows that SNSTopicArn to be the line in question now.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check your boto3 version

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was pretty silly - I specified the "folder" in the bucket name, when it should be part of the document name.

E.g. bucket-name/folder/document.png

Bucket name should be "bucket-name" and object name should be "folder/document.png".